# Axios HTTP backend call generates Opentelemetry span that is not correlated with the parent span

Tags: node.js, axios, instrumentation, open-telemetry, observability

I'm trying to perform manual instrumentation in NodeJs (v18.16.1) using opentelemetry. The scenario is very simple, I'm making an axios HTTP call to a dummy JSON API and I want to collect the generated trace.

Dependencies:

```
  "@opentelemetry/api": "^1.3.0",
  "@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node": "^0.38.0",
  "@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks": "^1.15.0",
  "@opentelemetry/instrumentation": "^0.41.0",
  "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http": "^0.35.1",
  "@opentelemetry/resources": "^1.9.1",
  "@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics": "^1.9.1",
  "@opentelemetry/sdk-node": "^0.35.1",
  "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base": "^1.9.1",
  "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node": "^1.9.1",
  "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions": "^1.9.1",
  "axios": "^1.4.0"
```

The setup is the following:

`otel/tracing.js` file:

```
const opentelemetry = require('@opentelemetry/api')
const { Resource } = require("@opentelemetry/resources");
const { SemanticResourceAttributes } = require("@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions");
const { NodeTracerProvider } = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node");
const { registerInstrumentations } = require("@opentelemetry/instrumentation");
const { ConsoleSpanExporter, SimpleSpanProcessor} = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base");
const { AsyncHooksContextManager } = require('@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks');
const {
    HttpInstrumentation,
} = require("@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http");


const contextManager = new AsyncHooksContextManager();

contextManager.enable()

opentelemetry.context.setGlobalContextManager(contextManager)


registerInstrumentations({
    instrumentations: [new HttpInstrumentation()],
});

const resource =
    Resource.default().merge(
        new Resource({
            [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'poc-otel-tracing',
            [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_VERSION]: "0.1.0",
        })
    );

const provider = new NodeTracerProvider({
    resource: resource
});

const exporter = new ConsoleSpanExporter();
const processor = new SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter);


provider.addSpanProcessor(processor);

provider.register();

// process.on('exit', function() {
//     void exporter.shutdown()
// });
```

`src/index.ts` file

```
import axios from "axios";

import opentelemetry, {Span} from "@opentelemetry/api";
const tracer = opentelemetry.trace.getTracer('poc-otel-tracing');

const API_BASE_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

const func = async() => {

    const rootSpan = tracer.startSpan('root-span')
    await apiCall(rootSpan)
    rootSpan.end()
}

const apiCall = async (parentSpan: Span) => {

    const ctx = opentelemetry.trace.setSpan(opentelemetry.context.active(), parentSpan)

    const childSpan = tracer.startSpan('api-call', undefined, ctx)

    try {
        await axios.get(API_BASE_URL);
    } catch (e) {
        childSpan.recordException(e);
    }

    childSpan.end()
}

void func()
```

Note that I'm using typescript, and I'm using `npm run build && node --require "./otel/tracing.js" dist/index.js` to run the compiled JS and to require the otel/tracing.js script.

The console output is the following:

```
{
  traceId: '15b261f7332feb1fdc79cff5a280529b',
  parentId: undefined,
  traceState: undefined,
  name: 'HTTPS GET',
  id: '477643c3a9536749',
  kind: 2,
  timestamp: 1690206903281000,
  duration: 128485,
  attributes: {
    'http.url': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    'http.method': 'GET',
    'http.target': '/posts',
    'net.peer.name': 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    'http.host': 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443',
    'net.peer.ip': '172.64.162.6',
    'net.peer.port': 443,
    'http.status_code': 200,
    'http.status_text': 'OK',
    'http.flavor': '1.1',
    'net.transport': 'ip_tcp'
  },
  status: { code: 0 },
  events: [],
  links: []
}
{
  traceId: 'ba35dbc454728c2bbc5b30a435dec3bb',
  parentId: 'a3897743fb82276c',
  traceState: undefined,
  name: 'api-call',
  id: 'ec3d00cb4ad95d26',
  kind: 0,
  timestamp: 1690206903278000,
  duration: 136158,
  attributes: {},
  status: { code: 0 },
  events: [],
  links: []
}
{
  traceId: 'ba35dbc454728c2bbc5b30a435dec3bb',
  parentId: undefined,
  traceState: undefined,
  name: 'root-span',
  id: 'a3897743fb82276c',
  kind: 0,
  timestamp: 1690206903278000,
  duration: 136633,
  attributes: {},
  status: { code: 0 },
  events: [],
  links: []
}
```

I don't understand why the span created for the axios http call is not correlated with the 'api-call' span (i.e. the span generated by axios should have 'api-call' as parent span) and should be part of the same trace.

Here's the output I would expect:

```
{
  traceId: 'ba35dbc454728c2bbc5b30a435dec3bb',
  parentId: 'a3897743fb82276c',
  traceState: undefined,
  name: 'HTTPS GET',
  id: '477643c3a9536749',
  kind: 2,
  timestamp: 1690206903281000,
  duration: 128485,
  attributes: {
    'http.url': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    'http.method': 'GET',
    'http.target': '/posts',
    'net.peer.name': 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    'http.host': 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443',
    'net.peer.ip': '172.64.162.6',
    'net.peer.port': 443,
    'http.status_code': 200,
    'http.status_text': 'OK',
    'http.flavor': '1.1',
    'net.transport': 'ip_tcp'
  },
  status: { code: 0 },
  events: [],
  links: []
}
{
  traceId: 'ba35dbc454728c2bbc5b30a435dec3bb',
  parentId: 'a3897743fb82276c',
  traceState: undefined,
  name: 'api-call',
  id: 'ec3d00cb4ad95d26',
  kind: 0,
  timestamp: 1690206903278000,
  duration: 136158,
  attributes: {},
  status: { code: 0 },
  events: [],
  links: []
}
{
  traceId: 'ba35dbc454728c2bbc5b30a435dec3bb',
  parentId: undefined,
  traceState: undefined,
  name: 'root-span',
  id: 'a3897743fb82276c',
  kind: 0,
  timestamp: 1690206903278000,
  duration: 136633,
  attributes: {},
  status: { code: 0 },
  events: [],
  links: []
}
```

Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause: The trace information is not propagated to the request (via axios in your case)

The fix:
extract trace info from the context, and inject it to request headers

```
const traceHeaders = {};
// inject context to trace headers for propagtion to the next service
propagation.inject(context.active(), traceHeaders);
// pass the trace headers to your request
const config = {
  headers: traceHeaders
};
await axios.get(API_BASE_URL, config);
```

Hope it works for you.
In case you need, I have the detailed setup documented [here](https://blog.stackademic.com/distributed-tracing-and-logging-using-express-js-winston-and-opentelemetry-e6652fb2ad80), with a link to a complete source